# PHP system("cd \"); not working

Tags: php, directory, system, cd

i used to use system commands through a php file ..cd \ was working then suddenly after a few tries it stopped :| no matter what i do

```
<?php
    $command = array("cd \","dir"); 
    $result = system($command[0], $return);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i figured out the problem..
the system() command in PHP does not create an instance of a cmd.exe
instead it only executes the command and exits.
that is why when you change directory using CD command
..the directory of the instance created by system() is changed and then exits.i hope my theory is correct xD

Answer (score 3):

Windows support forward slashes `/` as well as backslashes `\` so by using just forward slashes you should be cross compatible and less aggravation in the long run.

```
<?php
    $command = array("cd /","dir");
    $result = system($command[0], $return);
?>
```

[Wiki Path_Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29)

---

If you have any errors then please post them as the issue may not be the directory slashing because you said it was previously working.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$command = array("cd \\","dir");
```

Answer (score 0):

in linux mod:

```
$command = array("cd \\","dir");
```

in windows mod:

```
$command = array("cd /","dir");
```

Comment: What if you needed to migrate from windows to a linux OS, thats a lot of lines needed to be changed!

Answer (score 0):

PHP has its own change directory command: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php.  However that might not do exactly what you want.

Comment: http://lufi.dyndns-ip.com/cmd/?p=stackoverflow like what i said on greenmatt i wanted to use system commands..im actually running on xp right now

Answer (score 0):

In my testing (on Win 7 and XP), I found it necessary to escape the `\` for the directory (i.e. use `\\` instead).  Or you can use the forward slash.  Also, why not use PHP's [`chdir` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) instead of the system call?

```
<?php
    echo getcwd() . "\n";
    chdir("\\");
    echo getcwd() . "\n";
?>
```

Edit in response to the comment "... i am trying to create a cmd in a browser thing. ...":  The [system function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) just runs the command you specify and returns.  It will not (directly) affect the process which invoked the system command.  Thus, a system call with a command to change directory will not affect running PHP program's working directory, if that's what you are attempting.

Comment: http://lufi.dyndns-ip.com/cmd/ i wanted to use system commands..im actually running on xp right now

Comment: @kapitanluffy:  You may well have good reasons for wanting to use the system call, but your comment doesn't explain anything.  However, without a good reason, I'd think it easier to use the PHP call.

Comment: @RobertPitt:  While I was 99.44% certain the forward slash would work, I hadn't tested it yet.  It's now tested and the answer has been updated.

Comment: well your right..because i am experimenting on it .i am trying to create a cmd in a browser thing. ow and i am not planning to use power shell xD

Comment: @kapitanluffy: I've tested on XP and it works there.  My answer has been edited to reflect this.

Comment: did you try echoing the current directory after changing it? CD / then echo %cd%

Comment: @kapitanluffy:  Yes, I did `chdir('\\');` and then `echo getcwd();` (pretty much what is shown in the answer) and that worked on WinXP.  Also, see my answer for an explanation of why `system('cd /');` and similar commands won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you user two commands in the same calling of system(), using the delimiter?

```
<?php
$result = system("cd \;".$command[0], $return);?>
```